# Spring restfull web service vs CXF restful web service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I have a spring based project that need Rest API support for developing Rest client. This is a very high load application and I need a Rest implementation that with good performance. I've found in many article like one ***here*** that CXF is a great performance wise but initial effort in configuration and POC seems to be to much. Haven't found a lot of documentation regarding the API usage.

Can any one suggest weather I should use spring or CXF.

Comment: This is good site for start up...http://www.scribd.com/doc/13718489/Spring-and-CfX-by-Example

Comment: I went through the example and did a couple of my own POC's, but hardly found any different in ease of implementation. So from a coder's perspective both are similar. What I want to know is is there any trade-off's in using Spring Restful web serrvice or CXF with spring. More specifically is implementation of spring restful web-service not as per JAX-RS specifications.
I have seen links like one <a href="http://architects.dzone.com/articles/apache-cxf-vs-apache-axis-vs">here</a> but it compared spring ws with cxf. Can I use the same to infer that performance of CXF is better?

Answer (score 0):

You should also try Restlet and Jersey. By doing some demo projects with each one of them, you can find out which one best suit you.